# Magento 2 - offline payment have no entry in sales_order_status_history table

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, sales-order, order-status, order-history

I am working on the implementation of Track order functionality in Magento 2 in which I am using the **sales_order_status_history** table to get all status history related to the orders.

But this is working only for online payment whereas in the case of offline payment such as **COD, Check / Money Order**, etc, I am not getting any record in the **sales_order_status_history** table.

Whereas in **Magento 1** records are maintained for every order I placed.

Please help me by letting me know the actual cause of this.